# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar una columna tomando datos de otra tabla mediante JOIN en varias columnas?

Tags: mysql, update

Estoy un poco bloqueado con esto, a ver si alguien me da una mano.

Por un lado tengo una tabla llamada `liturgia_horas_lpatristicas`. En esa tabla tengo una columna llamada `id_liturgia` con valores como este: `0708310401`. El objetivo es normalizar ese valor, que pensé en un principio como una especie de código combinado donde 07`representa una cosa,`08`otra cosa,`31` otra cosa y así.

Para ello creé en esa tabla una columna nueva sin datos que se llama `id_breviario`.

Por otro lado creé una nueva tabla llamada `liturgia_breviario` con las columnas: `id_breviario, id_tiempo, id_ciclo, id_semana, id_dia`.

La normalización consiste en que tengo que actualizar la columna `id_breviario` de `liturgia_horas_lpatristicas`  con el valor correspondiente en `liturgia_breviario`.

Muestro un ejemplo de los datos:

En `liturgia_horas_lpatristicas` tengo datos así:

```
id_patristica     id_liturgia     id_breviario     
-----------------------------------------------
   76589           0708310401         NULL
   76590           0708310501         NULL
```

Y en `liturgia_breviario` tengo filas así:

```
id_breviario     id_tiempo     id_ciclo     id_semana       id_dia
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      1              7            8             31           4
      2              7            8             31           5
      3              7            8             31           6
```

### Resultado esperado

```
id_patristica     id_liturgia     id_breviario     
-----------------------------------------------
   76589           0708310401         1
   76590           0708310501         2
```

Son muchas filas, por lo que necesitaría un `UPDATE` que funcione mediante JOIN`, poniendo en cada fila el` id_brevisrio`que corresponda. El criterio sería determinar los valores de join basándose en subtrings de la columna`id_liturgia`, algo así:

```
SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,1,2) t,
SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,3,2) c,
SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,5,2) s,
SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,7,2) d
```

Ahí yo tendría en `t,c,s,d` los valores que podría usar como criterio para encontrar el `id_breviario` en la tabla `liturgia_breviario`, pero realmente no sé cómo armar la consulta para que me haga la actualización de cada fila.

El esquema de UPDATE basado en otra tabla que conozco ese este:

```
UPDATE liturgia_horas_lpatristicas t2, 
    (SELECT id_breviario FROM liturgia_breviario WHERE -- criterios de t1 ) t1
SET 
    t2. id_breviario = t1. id_breviario
WHERE -- criterios de t2;
```

Pero esto no hace un `JOIN` dinámico para actualizar cada valor con su correspondiente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Otra opción es la siguiente:

```sql
UPDATE
  `liturgia_horas_lpatristicas`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      `liturgia_breviario`.`id_breviario`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        LPAD(`liturgia_breviario`.`id_tiempo`, 2, 0),
        LPAD(`liturgia_breviario`.`id_ciclo`, 2, 0),
        LPAD(`liturgia_breviario`.`id_semana`, 2, 0),
        LPAD(`liturgia_breviario`.`id_dia`, 2, 0)
      ) `grupo_liturgia_breviario`
    FROM
      `liturgia_breviario`
    GROUP BY 
      `liturgia_breviario`.`id_breviario`
  ) `der`
SET
  `liturgia_horas_lpatristicas`.`id_breviario` = `der`.`id_breviario`
WHERE
  LEFT(`liturgia_horas_lpatristicas`.`id_liturgia`, 8) = `der`.`grupo_liturgia_breviario`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1554fb08ec617ee6ed9b94f22f4be7fb).

Al no disponer de las estructuras reales de las tablas, inferí algunos tipos de datos de las columnas que seguramente no serán los de sus tablas.

Comment: Sorprendente respuesta que resuelve el problema de la forma esperada. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 8):

La relación entre las dos tablas, entiendo, podría definirse así:

```
SELECT lhl.id_liturgia,
       lb.id_breviario
       FROM liturgia_horas_lpatristicas lhl
       INNER JOIN liturgia_breviario lb
            ON lb.id_tiempo = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,1,2)
               AND lb.id_ciclo = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,3,2)
               AND lb.id_semana = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,5,2)
               AND lb.id_dia = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,7,2)
```

Con esta consulta podría "pivotear" en el `update`

```
UPDATE liturgia_horas_lpatristicas
      SET id_breviario = T2.id_breviario
      FROM liturgia_horas_lpatristicas T1
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT lhl.id_liturgia,
                   lb.id_breviario
                   FROM liturgia_horas_lpatristicas lhl
                   INNER JOIN liturgia_breviario lb
                        ON lb.id_tiempo = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,1,2)
                           AND lb.id_ciclo = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,3,2)
                           AND lb.id_semana = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,5,2)
                            AND lb.id_dia = lhl.SUBSTRING(id_liturgia,7,2)
      ) T2
      ON T1.id_liturgia = T2.id_liturgia
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio. Aunque me he quedado con la respuesta de @wchiquito, hace justo lo que buscaba y es más entendible.